# Convergence of this priori error in FEM?

Tags: inequality, hilbert-spaces, integral-inequality, finite-element-method

Problem

[image]

**My attempt**

I think *h* is the size of the mesh. 
*C* is a constant which probably depends on the size of the mesh, I think. 
I think the error converges linearly and dependent on the size of the mesh. 
However, I think this is not what is wanted here.

**Extension by Daw's comment**

[image]

**What can you say about the converge of this priori estimate?**

Comment: The answer depends very much on the precise definition of $V_h$. Otherwise $h$ could be everything. And you want $C$ to be independent of $h$. If $C  = 1/h$ then the estimate would not have any purpose.

Comment: @daw I added the definition of Vh. Is this now enough? Do you need something more?

Comment: You need an interpolation or best approximation error estimate. There is no definition of $V_h$ above, it could as well be $V_h=\{0\}$.

Comment: @daw I defined Vh again. The problem is Poisson so this one can be what they are looking for.